# Make button occupy full height inside a TD element in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, html-table

I've been trying to make a `button` which is inside a `td` cell in IE9. It's working fine on chrome and firefox (although the latter involved bubbling up `height:100%` to the `td`, `tr` and `table` elements). Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem using only CSS?

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="stuff">stuff</span>
    </td>
    <td class="the-td">
      <button class="problem-here">
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>more stuff</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td, tr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.problem-here {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.stuff {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.the-td {
  width: 70%
}

button span {
  display: block;  
}
```

And, finally, here's a fiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/vh3jodap/10/

Thanks in advance

EDIT: here's a pic of what's happening right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNiFI.png

Comment: unable to test on msie9 right now. try display:block on the <button>

Comment: Had already tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: seen it. unfortunately i don't think a solution for this exists. not a css only one at least. feel free to prove me wrong though

Answer (score 0):

In IE, in order for an element to have `height:100%;`, all parent elements must have `height:100%;`.

Any parent missing the `height:100%;` will cause IE to ignore it all.

**Warning** There's a high probability your table will grow bigger entirely

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried giving a `height: 100%` from the `button` all the way over to the `body`... The button's height is still only them sum of the two inner spans =/